# java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am creating an Android app and I have implemented a client server using a WAMP server. I have created my php file, the server is running and a simple version of my php file was inserting data successfully into my mysql database. In my app I have included an `AsyncTask` java file in order to insert my data. I am sure my url string is wrong and that's why it is printing the following error:

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

I am testing my app on a Samsung S4 so no emulator replies to change my ip string to 10.0.2.2. I have used localhost, 127.0.0.1 and my IP adress which I found by running ipconfig in cmd...nothing works and it is printing the same error. I read 15-20 similar questions and I still don't know what to do.

Internet permission exists on my manifest and my phone is connected via Wi-Fi in my router. (I also tried with my phones 4G and this did not work either).

Below you can find my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
  Context ctx;
  BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
  {
    this.ctx = ctx;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
    super.onPreExecute();
  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params)
  {
    String create_url = "http://217.137.144.65/myapp/create.php";
    String method = params[0];

    if(method.equals("create"))
    {
        String name = params[1];
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(create_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("exCatName","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            return "Category Created Successfully";
        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
  {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result)
  {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CreateNewCategoryActivity extends Activity
{
  private ImageView backImageView, saveImageView;
  private EditText nameEditText;
  String categoryName;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_new_category);

    backImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backImageView);
    saveImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.saveImageView);
    nameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);

    backImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            backMethod();
        }
    });

    saveImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            createNewCategoryMethod();
        }
    });
  }

  public void createNewCategoryMethod()
  {
    categoryName = nameEditText.getText().toString();
    String method = "create";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method, categoryName);
    finish();
  }

  public void backMethod()
  {
    //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BalanceActivity.class));
    finish();
  }
}
```

php file:

```
<?php
require "init.php";

$exCategories_ID = "1";
$exCatName = $_POST["name"];

$sql_query = "insert into Expense_Categories values

('$exCategories_ID','$exCatName');";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
{
echo "<h3>Data Insertion Success...</h3>";
}

else
{
echo "Data insertion error...".mysqli_error($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: are you sure 217.137.144.65 is your LOCAL ip address?

Comment: localhost is also wrong, you need to use the local ip from the pc in the same network, for example, phone could be 192.168.0.15 and pc 192.168.0.16

Comment: I dont know, it shows online when i click what is my IP. When i go in the cmd it shows my a different one wgich si somethign liek this 192.168.X.X. I have used that one and with this it does not print anything in my log cat and still no data are inserted. By the way i edited my post and changed that IP in 'localhost'. This was the way it was intented to be posted .

Comment: OK i understand sir. How can i check this then in order to be sure that both have the same ip?

Comment: use ipconfig, but check for your local ip (that 192.168.x.x looks like the ip you need). put that in the create_url String

Comment: I used that Ip adress i found in the cmd and it throws another error.

Comment: This is the error i have now sir. http://prntscr.com/aun61w

Comment: ok, so now you are reaching the server, but the create.php file is not found in that location.. try to hit that url in a browser and see what happens

Comment: if i hit 192.168.0.1/myapp/create.php it sais 404 not found file not found but if i hit localhost/myapp/create.php i get this  http://prntscr.com/aun8al

Comment: ok, so the problem is that 192.168.0.1 is not the ip of the pc, can you share a screenshot of the ipconfig command?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/aunase thats the screenshot. For your inforamtion I have tested the 192.168.0.3 but it prints nothing in my logcat so i though that is not the one i need.

Comment: ok, so 192.168.0.3 is what you need.. if logcat shows nothing, is ok :) it should be working now, can you check that?

Comment: As previously nothing got inserted in my database :((. I also have a toast that must be displayed. You can find it in the end of the first activity i posted. Toast did nto appear (while with the other ip adresses it appeared but emtpy without printing my message ) at all this time and nothing happened. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to debug? i need more info to help you.. we are getting closer

Comment: Please tell me what you want me to screenshot for you? I clicked the debug button in my android studio which is near the run button and this apperead http://prntscr.com/aungb8 I dont know if thats what you need

Comment: You cna close this thread. I ve solved the problem many days ago. Thank you all for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1
>   (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

`String create_url = "http://localhost/myapp/create.php";`

is wrong, the correct one is

`String create_url = "http://192.168.0.3/myapp/create.php";`

being `192.168.0.3` the local ip of your pc (server)

Answer (score 1):

I got same type of problem. My PC contains `MySQL` installed and Then I have installed `WAMP`. Then the problem is occured. WAMP containing mysql port number and my PC's MySQL are conflicting.

So you can uninstall your PC's MySQL first and restart and use WAMP's MySQL. Then the problem will be solved.

Comment: Indeed i have installed the mql workbench and today i installed the wamp server without unistalling the sml workbech. Do you reckon to go in the control panel and unistall the workbench?

Comment: Do i need to unistall something else as well on top of the workbench? because i still have  a program which is called MySql Notifier (1.1.6). I remember this got there when i first installed the workbench. I started the wamp server and only 1 of 2 services run now instead of 2-2 like before because a mySQL57 service is running at the moment. What do i have to do?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/aun34k     I have these SQL 'things' in my computer as well. Must all be unistalled? If yes all of them or some of them?

Comment: For solving your coding problem, you just uninstall mysql workbench. If it is needed, you can install it later.

Comment: Well i did unistall the workbench only and no other mysql programs as like the ones you saw in the screenshot. And it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

To access `localhost` you should use local IPv4 + server PORT for `localhost`.

How to get this IPv4:
https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-local-ip-address

**KOTLIN async request:**

```
private val client = OkHttpClient()

fun run() {
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("http://192.168.0.104:5000/api/post/latest")
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            response.use {
                if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

                for ((name, value) in response.headers) {
                    println("$name: $value")
                }

                println(response.body!!.string())
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Install** OkHttp: https://square.github.io/okhttp/